# Increase numbers in a string

Tags: c#, string

[POST HAS BEEN EDITED FOR CLARITY, SOLUTION PROVIDED STILL APPLIES]

I want to increase all the numbers in a string by an already pre-determined value.
For instance, I have the following string:

```
"a 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3\n
b 4/4/4 5/5/5 6/6/6\n"
...
```

I want to read those numbers from each line and add a value to them and put them back in place.
I am working with integers.

e.g. (random numbers)

```
"a 1/2/3 3/4/5 5/6/7\n
b 4/4/4 5/6/7 9/9/14\n"
```

By adding 5 becomes

```
"a 6/7/8 8/9/10 10/11/12\n
b 9/9/9 10/11/12 14/14/19\n"
```

Comment: Well... what have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: Can you show what the result for this example would be?  What if there were a 9?

Comment: Floating numbers allowed eg. `1.23` ?

Comment: @InBetween please note _["Not all questions benefit from including code..."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)_ and _[Is it always a good idea to demand the OP “post some code”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286760/585968)_

Comment: @MickyD and that is relevant to this particular question in what way? "*I need to do this, please write code for me*", which is basically what this question is, is not the way to ask anything in SO. If you don't even know where to begin in trying to resolve a simple task as this one then maybe you shouldn't even be asking this question and maybe you should be going back to getting your basics right. My comment is precisely aimed in making this obvious.

Comment: It's a typical StackOverflow user throwing a fit, it's okay.
I did have some solutions in my head. But I am glad I did ask here because other user showed that Regex could do this, which is way more efficient!
I rearranged the question to be more clear. Sorry english is not my first language.

Comment: Completely agree with you @JoséPintor.  Some people seem to think that all posts must show an attempt or mention what code isn’t working which isn’t the rules at all. Some much rather downvote you and nominate the question for closure.  Don’t be put off by them, they are a minority.  I think I’m the only one who upvoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following. Search for digits with regex, parse it to int, increase by some value, convert back to string.

```
string input = @"a x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3\n
b x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3\n";

string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+",
    m => (int.Parse(m.Value) + 1).ToString());

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Wow. I was completely oblivious of the fact, Regex.Replace could do this! Awesome to know.

Comment: @JoséPintor - just a heads up, this code does the same thing to floating point numbers, as I described in my answer, you never replied if that is an issue or not, just want to let you know

Comment: @RandRandom thanks for pointing that out, luckly I am only working with intergers

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, currently ignores float and would increment each `1.23` by the value you specified eg. inrementing by `2` would result in `3.45`.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str = "a x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3\nb x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3\n";
    var newStr = IncrementBy(str, 2); 
    
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine(newStr);
}

private static string IncrementBy(string str, int increment)
{
    var newStr = "";
    var digitChars = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        var currentChar = i <= str.Length ? str[i] : (char)0;
        if (!char.IsDigit(currentChar))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(digitChars))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(digitChars, out int value))
                {
                    value += increment;
                    newStr += value.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    newStr += digitChars;
                }
            }
            
            if (i <= str.Length)
                newStr += currentChar;
            
            digitChars = "";
        }
        else
        {
            digitChars += str[i];
        }
    }   
    
    return newStr;
}
```

Demo:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/mv3Xbz

Comment: Thanks for your effort. As you might have noticed, Regex can also do this!

Comment: This would not produce the result in the OP's example.

Comment: @ScottHunter - could you show me the issue, I am unable to see it.

Comment: What does your solution do w/ `14`?  In OP's example, that gets changed to 19 (when adding 5).

Comment: @ScottHunter - sorry, for my late reply was busy - thanks for the explanation but I still fail to understand where the issue should be, here a screenshot of the result I am getting - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LQ0h.png

Comment: @ScottHunter - the issue prevents me from sleeping, do you mind to give it another try explaining me where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wont need numbers using more than one character. The string builder needs a "Using System.Text;" :

```
String text = "a x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3\nb x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3\n";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);
Console.WriteLine(text);
for(int i = 0; i< text.Length; i++)
{
    int num = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(text[i].ToString(), out num))
        //int.TryParse((sb[i]+""), out int num)
    {
        sb[i] = (num+1).ToString().ToCharArray(0,1)[0];
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(sb);
```

The text output from this is:
a x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3
b x1/x2/x3 y1/y2/y3 z1/z2/z3

a x2/x3/x4 y2/y3/y4 z2/z3/z4
b x2/x3/x4 y2/y3/y4 z2/z3/z4